# Serverside EventEmitter triggered once per socket | Node.js / Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm having an issue that I haven't been able to solve on my own for the last few days and am really hoping for some help. I'm new to socketio and nodejs and have thrown myself in the deep end. I believe that the event listener is being created multiple times due to being associated with the socket function 'connection', however  have been unable to find a way around this.

Now that I am able to send events client to server and vice versa, I am trying to understand how to use event listeners to send them server to server.

p.s i know there are cleaner ways to operate this game logic and have some ideas going forward but just trying to grasp the fundamentals first.

Thanks!
Riley

app.js

```
gameStartBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){ // On clicking start game counter
socket.emit('gameStart', {
    lobbyDuration: lobbyDuration.value,
    nightDuration: nightDuration.value,
    dayDuration: dayDuration.value,
    groupVoteDuration: groupVoteDuration.value
});
```

server.js

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected', socket.id); //assign socketid and send
  socket.join("room-"+roomno); //join room

  socket.on('gameStart', function(data){
    dayDuration = data.dayDuration;
    groupVoteDuration = data.groupVoteDuration;
    console.log('testing123');
  srv.emit('timerStart', { // Night time
    countdownDuration: data.nightDuration,
    currPhase: 'Night Time'
  });
  // only triggered once
  srv.emit('triggerEvent', {
    triggerTime: data.nightDuration,
    nextEvent: 'dayPhase'
  });
});

  // triggered 1x per client
srv.on('dayPhase', function(data){
  
  srv.emit('timerStart', { // Day time
    countdownDuration: dayDuration,
    currPhase: 'Day Time'
  });

  srv.emit('triggerEvent', {
    triggerTime: dayDuration,
    nextEvent: 'groupVotePhase'
  });

});

  // triggered 1x per client
srv.on('groupVotePhase', function(){

  srv.emit('timerStart', { // Group Vote time
    countdownDuration: groupVoteDuration,
    currPhase: 'Voting Time'
  });

  
  srv.emit('triggerEvent', {
    triggerTime: groupVoteDuration,
    nextEvent: 'gameEnd'
  });

});

// triggered 1x per client extra broken
srv.on('gameEnd', function(){
  console.log('game ended losers');
});
```

Output with 1 user:

```
testing123
3
2
1
dayPhase
3
2
1
groupVotePhase
3
2
1
gameEnd
game ended losers
0
```

3 Users Output:

```
testing123
3
2
1
dayPhase
3
2
1
groupVotePhase
groupVotePhase
groupVotePhase
3
2
1
gameEnd
game ended losers
game ended losers
game ended losers
gameEnd
game ended losers
game ended losers
game ended losers
gameEnd
game ended losers
game ended losers
game ended losers
gameEnd
game ended losers
game ended losers
game ended losers
gameEnd
game ended losers
game ended losers
game ended losers
gameEnd
game ended losers
game ended losers
game ended losers
gameEnd
game ended losers
game ended losers
game ended losers
gameEnd
game ended losers
game ended losers
game ended losers
gameEnd
game ended losers
game ended losers
game ended losers
0
```

Comment: Greetings! I think what you are really looking for is showed with examples in the documentation of socket.io. Take a look! https://socket.io/docs/v4/using-multiple-nodes/#Passing-events-between-nodes 

They are called Adapters and there is a link at the bottom of the page I've provided you

If it's not of any use for your case, make sure you let me know.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the suggestion, everything I'm seeing in those pieces of documentation seem to be talking about sending information between multiple server nodes whereas I'm only running the one. I'm trying to make my game logic run on server-side and only input and output on the client-side. To keep everything synchronized. I'm only using one server instance but trying to trigger server-side events similar to calling a function in vanilla javascript but am finding that the event listener is being duplicated by the socket.io instances. Please let me know if I have misunderstood. :)

Comment: For anyone seeing this in the future, this was caused by having an event listener inside a socket.on event. This would create the listener each time the socket.on is called. When the event listener is triggered, it does so once for every listener that the socket on has created.